# What is the fastest lens available for a DSLR?

Tags: lens, aperture

I've seen references to f1.2 lenses. I was wondering, are there any faster lenses available for a DSLR mount?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_speed#Fast_lenses

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/minimum-and-maximum-apertures

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> are there any faster lenses available for a DSLR mount?

To answer your question, not really, though it's possible to argue based on your definition of DSLR and your definition of available.

If you relax your definition of DSLR to digital rangefinders, then yes, you can include the Leica Noctilux, which is still in production. And if you relax your definition of "available", Canon made a 50 f/1.0 for the EF mount which can be obtained second hand. There are also many more fast lenses that can be mounted via an adaptor.

But practically, the fastest production DSLR lenses are the Canon EF 85mm f/1.2L and EF 50mm f/1.2L, and the manual Nikon Nikkor 50mm f/1.2 AIS.

Comment: No mention of the Canon 50 f/.95? For shame...

Answer (score 19):

Carl Zeiss 50mm f/0.7

http://www.flickr.com/photos/torek/3485651814/

Leica also makes a 50mm f/1.0 lens which is actually available it seems and might be more ...usable.
http://lensbuyersguide.com/en/lens/show/Leica/NOCTILUX-M_50mm_f1.0

Comment: Yay! for the good old german company ... if only I could afford their prices today ;)

Comment: I would argue neither of those are available for a DSLR mount.  They're available for the rangefinder M mount :)

Comment: True enough, although there are adapters.

Comment: The story about the Zeiss 50mm f0.7 is interesting, there were only two units manufactured, for the Apollo program (yes, they were used to take the pictures of the lunar landing!) and one of them ended up in Stanley Kubrik's hands to shoot Barry Lindon :)

Comment: Most recent Leica Noctilux is down to F0.95 now.  Still works on any M mount like M3 =)

Answer (score 7):

There is also [50mm 0.95 lens from Noktor](http://noktor.com/products.php) for Micro 4/3rds.

[image]

(photo from the [noktor website](http://noktor.com))

Micro 4/3rds is a mirror-less system so it is not a real DSLR lens as such, but it seems that there are also planning to make models for other mounts as on the main page there is a product survey: "What mount would you like to see lenses designed for?" with options:Canon EF,Nikon F,Four Thirds and PL Cinema Mount. Hard to say if they would manage to make it equally fast for other mounts

Comment: The Noktor seems to be a converted [C-mount lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mount) which means it barely covers the 4/3 sensor. Making a 50/0.95 to cover even a APS-C would be a daunting technical task.

Comment: That's a rebranded Senko VFA5095H CCTV lens but with a micro 4/3rds mount. Given that, I can't see how they how they're going to release it with a Canon EF or Nikon F mount (both of which have a much larger registration distance i.e. minimum distance from the back of the lens to the sensor) unless it's going to be a lock-the-mirror-up job, designed for video.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the fastest lens (that is actually availabe) is currently the leica 50mm f/0.95

http://en.leica-camera.com/photography/m_system/lenses/5915.html

Answer (score 3):

For me, the fastest lense was the [50mm f/1.0 from Canon](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/standard/ef_50_10l_usm.html), but it's discontinued now.

Otherwise I agree with chills42, but Leica Ms are not DSLRs.

Answer (score 2):

The Zeiss 50mm f0.75 cannot be mounted on an SLR, as the rear element would hit the mirror.
The fastest ever SLR lens would therefore have to be a customised 65mm f0.75 Astro-Berlin Tachon (Sonnar design).

Answer (score 0):

[Rayxar](http://www.google.com/images?q=rayxar) makes lenses with f1/0.75 apertures.

Comment: Definitely not an SLR lens. But this http://hannu.mallat.fi/oddities/rayxar/rayxar.html is more informative than the google images link....

Answer (score 0):

Cosina has a f/0.95 lens Micro 4/3 mount - Voigtlander 25mm f/0.95 Micro 4/3 Nokton

http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/lenses/voigtlander_f095_25mm_micro_43_nocton.shtml

Comment: Micro 4/3 cameras [are not DSLRs](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-makes-a-camera-an-slr). For a DSLR, [50mm f/1.1](http://www.voigtlaender.de/cms/voigtlaender/voigtlaender_cms.nsf/id/pa_fdih7s8jbr.html) with an adapter is the fastest lens offered under Voigtländer name.