# Is Fujifilm HS25EXR a DSLR? Or is it considered to be a compact camera?

Tags: dslr, fujifilm, bridge-camera, camera-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes a camera an “SLR”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-makes-a-camera-an-slr)

I am purchasing Fujifilm HS25EXR camera. On some websites it is listed as a DSLR, but on some it is not. Can someone help me understand if it is a Digital SLR or not.

Comment: It is not a DSLR, see the duplicate question above

Answer (score 0):

This camera is not a DSLR (Digital Single Lens Reflex) as it does not have an optical viewfinder that "sees" through the same lens that the sensor sees through. In DSLRs the view in the viewfinder is provided by a **Reflex** mirror that moves out of the way when the picture is captured.

---

This is however probably a duplicate of the [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-makes-a-camera-an-slr) Matt Grum mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a DSLR and this answered by the [duplicate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-makes-a-camera-an-slr).

It is not a compact either and you can see that is is not *compact*! Neither is it a P&S because it has full manual controls, including manual focus.

Such cameras are  called *bridge* or *prosumer* cameras because they are somewhere in between. They have very similar image quality to compacts because they often use the same small sensors (For the HS25 EXR that is the same one as in as the [F770 EXR](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/fuji/f770exr)) but they have more more capabilities than the *typical* compact.

See my [Demystifying Digital Camera Types](http://www.neocamera.com/article/camera_types) article for more details.