# LCD Screen Is On While Camera Is Off

Tags: canon, film

I was shooting a roll of film and was done for the day, I left the roll inside as it still has a few photos and turned off my point and shoot. But the LCD panel stays on indicating how many shots I have left and that there is a roll inside. No matter what I do the LCD panel stays on, I don't want the battery to run out because of it but I also don't want to take out the batteries in case it rewinds the film and I lose the shots left. I read the manual and I can't find anything. It's a Canon EOS Rebel T2.

Comment: small point of order... a Canon EOS camera is not a "point and shoot". It's a [SLR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8211) camera.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal in a film camera. There's nothing to worry about - it's a relatively low-tech LCD display - not like the fancy screen on the back of a modern digital camera. Think how long the tiny battery in a digital watch lasts for. I think you don't need to worry about your batteries being drained.

Page 12 of [the manual](https://cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_eos_rebel-t2_300x.pdf) just says...

[image: When not using the camera, set the Mode Dial to]

Comment: The LCD technology takes almost no power by itself, it's the backlight that you find in all modern ones that drains your battery.  The older LCDs were reflective so they didn't need a backlight.