# Is there theoretical limit on the minimal focal length for a given sensor size?

Tags: focal-length, optics, physics

There seems to be a limit, around 0.33, on [the fastest possible aperture](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/what-are-the-theoretical-minimum-and-maximum-apertures). Is there a theoretical limit on how wide a non-fisheye lens can be? That is, what is the minimal possible focal lens for a given sensor size?

Comment: The theoretical limit with typical glass used for camera lenses for maximum aperture is f/0.5. If one had a diamond large enough and pure enough, one could cut a lens with a theoretical maximum aperture of f/0.235 because diamond has such a high index of refraction. That f/0.33 lens was a marketing gimmick that didn't actually work.

Comment: To clarify the question: You're looking for math to support what the shortest focal *length* of a lens you can get, for a given sensor/film size, before noticeable 'fisheye distortions' creep in? - You may need to define what level of acceptable distortions would be for a helpful and valid answer.

Comment: @TheLuckless, Yes, I'm asking about the shortest focal *length*. A ballpark info would be sufficient; forget about the non-fisheye clause.

Comment: Well, 0mm is pretty much a hard limit for focal length. Probably not very useful, though. But, it does pretty much affirmatively answer "is there a theoretical limit ...".

Comment: @twalberg, :-) What about a positive limit?

Comment: I'd suspect the answer would vary tremendously between mirrorless cameras and DSLRs due to their different flange focal distances. Also, crop factor will definitely affect the result (think about iPhone). At least 4.5mm Sigma is available for Canon crop sensor cameras, and 8mm Canon for both full frame and crop sensor cameras. Oh, but both are fisheye lenses.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of any *theoretical* minimum focal length (with respect to sensor size), there is a *useful* limit.

On 35mm film and full frame sensors, the current widest-angle lens that is useful is 8mm. There are 4.5mm lenses that are meant for crop-sensor cameras, that *could* be mounted on full frame cameras, but there's no point in doing so. Why?

The 8mm lenses for full-frame cameras project a full-circle fisheye image that is just shy of 24mm in diameter, which corresponds to the narrow dimension of the sensor. That means the entire fisheye circle is imaged uncropped on the sensor. But that also means there is a lot of sensor area that is unused, outside of the image circle projected by the lens.

The 4.5mm lenses for crop sensor cameras project a similar full-circle fisheye image that is just shy of 15mm in diameter, which corresponds to the narrow dimension of Canon's APS-C sensor. So you *could* mount a Sigma 4.5mm lens onto a full frame Nikon or Canon, but the 15mm-diameter image wouldn't be taking advantage of the larger sensor size of the full frame camera.

Both the full frame 8mm lenses, and the crop frame 4.5mm lenses, have similar angles of view, over 180°. Actually, there is quite a bit of variability in the upper end of angle of view amongst all full-circle fisheye lenses. But that variability really doesn't matter, because the projected images from the extreme edges of the lens's view is compressed and distored into a rather thin ring near the circumference of the fisheye image circle. Even if you remap the projection at the edge of the circle in software, there's likely to be significant and severe distortion, color separation, vingetting, etc.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't apply to non-fisheye lenses though: for rectilinear projection, reducing focal length always results in a wider view. Nevertheless, I don't see rectangular full frame lenses with focal length below 12 mm on the market. I wonder whether there's a physical reason for that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it doesn't apply for non-fisheye lenses. _Part_ of the reason (I'm sure there's more) why you can't increase the angle of view arbitrarily close to 180° by shortening the focal length though it because at a certain point you're no longer talking about _thin lenses_ (i.e., the thin lens approximation no longer holds).