# Is there a negative numerical aperture(NA)?

Tags: lens

[Collimated beam - Negative lens]
Can this situation call negative NA?

or Is there a exist any negative NA situation?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the theoretical minimum and maximum apertures?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/what-are-the-theoretical-minimum-and-maximum-apertures)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's really not such a thing as a negative numerical aperture. Understand that NA is about an *image forming lens*, bringing the incoming light (in the case you mentioned, collimated) to a single focus point. Meaning, a net-convex system.

I understand that it's tempting to look at an equation such as *NA* = *n* sin *θ*, and wonder what meaning can be inferred if *n* or *θ* were negative.

- In the case of negative index of refraction (negative *n*), it doesn't change NA. The classical formulation of numerical aperture didn't anticipate metamaterials with negative refractive indices. In that case, the equation should probably be updated to *NA* = |*n*| sin *θ*.
- negative *θ* is nonsensical. The acceptance angle is a measurement of a real-world value, where in this case negative angle doesn't exist in reality.