# What is the highest (slowest) f-number in a produced lens?

Tags: lens, lens-design

Kind of what it says on the tin. There's [plenty](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/what-are-the-theoretical-minimum-and-maximum-apertures) [of questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6954/what-is-the-fastest-lens-available-for-a-dslr) on Photography.SE about the fastest lens out there, but let's go the other way - what's the highest (non-infinite) f-number on a production lens? One-offs and weird stuff like [this](https://petapixel.com/2013/08/06/carl-zeiss-super-q-gigantar-40mm-f0-33-the-fastest-lens-ever-made/) are fair game.

Specifically, I'm curious about two things:

1. What is the highest "bottom" f-number on a production lens?
2. What is the absolute highest f-number on a production lens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends if by production you mean in production now, or has been in production in the past and I will generally reference lenses for typical photography applications.

The [Hasselblad 500mm Appo-Tesar](http://imagesandcameras.com/hasselblad-lenses) made for the V system could be stopped to f/45 (and is the smallest aperture in my collection and the smallest I have come across). The [350mm Tele-Tessar, 250mm Sonnor, 120mm and 135mm S-Planar](http://imagesandcameras.com/hasselblad-lenses) could also be stopped to F/45. However all of these lenses are currently out of production. With that in mind a lot of their more modern H-System lenses have similar specs.

[The Cooke PS945 can stop down to a whopping F/90](http://www.cookeoptics.com/l/largeformat.html) and appears to still be in production.

Keep in mind that since [F-Stop is calculated in comparison to the front (entrance) element as well as the focal length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number). Thus a [quite sizable front element is needed for say an F/1.2 50mm](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/50mm-f12.htm) lens while an F/45 500mm lens can be achieved with a relatively easy to machine hole size and modest diameter front element.

Also for the record, [that Zeiss F/0.33 lens never actually worked.](https://www.ormsdirect.co.za/blog/2013/08/07/the-worlds-fastest-fake-lens-zeiss-40mm-f0-33/)

On a similar note, generally speaking, photographers have always wanted faster lenses to allow the use of higher shutter speeds (and possibly slower film/ISO speeds) in low light. Practically speaking, [ambient sunlight never really gets bright enough to warrant some extremely small F/Stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value) for a somewhat "standard" exposure. There may be some desire for motion blur (slow shutter speed, small aperture setting) but any kind of [extra reduction can be compensated for with an ND filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral-density_filter). Technically we may even be better at making tiny apertures than huge fast lenses there is just no practical need for them.

Comment: A nit:  the F/number is related to the **entrance pupil** as your link states.  This is not necessarily the same as (or even the same diameter as) the front lens element.

Comment: Edited the verbiage to reflect.

Comment: I realize this question isn't really of practical interest, for the reasons you've stated - I was just curious :)

Comment: I merely mention that to illustrate that high aperture lenses are easy to make (far easier than their fast aperture counterparts) but not really in demand so an F/90 lens is strange in and of its self.

Comment: You never answered the questions 1 and 2!!!

Comment: F/90 as far as I can find

Comment: @Goat   Pinholes are in production :-)

Comment: Well that is actually true yes, I disregards pinholes, but you are factually right about it. So, I'll have to give you that one @Carl.

Comment: @Dave the F/90 is certainly smaller than anything I ever seen, but what is the widest aperture? I'll say the f/0.95 since the Zeiss Planar 50mm f/0.7 wasn't a production lens, although the fastest lens ever made.

Comment: The [Handevision IBELUX 40mm f/0.85](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1056300&gclid=CjwKEAiA2abEBRCdx7PqqunM1CYSJABf3qvapJ6l037u5GxbyhUXl5oD2W6IR09UO5jpMe0WkYtDxRoCbVTw_wcB&Q=&ap=y&c3api=1876%2C52934714882%2C&is=REG&A=details) is faster than the Noctilux if we are not considering Kubrick's 0.7's as production lenses.

Answer (score 3):

I'm stretching the definition of "lens" a bit, but certainly the slowest imaging device you can buy is a 1-micron precision pinhole.  See for example the products from [Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1400).
Any smaller than that (and practically speaking, any smaller than about 5 microns) and diffraction effects will ruin your image. :-) .

Comment: I have actually used an 8um pinhole on my 350D (I have a c-mount for it). It wasn't very successful.

Comment: Regarding the "1-micron precision pinhole" response...what would the equivalent f-number be? I've also heard the diffraction explanation in the past, so there's a limit to practicality...use whatever you have, and add a ND filter to get a longer exposure. You can calculate hyperfocal distance, and adapt accordingly.

Comment: @dtphoto  Well, the depth of focus is so huge for pinhole cameras that the concept of F/# pretty much collapses.

Comment: You never answered the questions 1 and 2!!!